# Add mass action to product grid Magento2

Tags: magento2, massaction, product-grid

For adding massaction to product grid I use next code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <massaction name="listing_massaction" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions">
            <action name="copyoptions">
                <settings>
                    <url path="modulename/index/massSendConfirmation"/> <!-- your custom controller to handle request -->
                    <type>copyoptions</type>
                    <label translate="true">Copy Product Options</label>
                </settings>
            </action>
        </massaction>
        <paging name="listing_paging"/>
    </listingToolbar>
</listing>
```

It works, How can I add input field to this place [image]

I need it to set product id in this input. 
Who can give any information?

Comment: any luck with this ? Did you manage to solve this ?

Comment: No, did not solve

Comment: Check my [module here](https://github.com/theshreyas/magento-2-quickies/tree/main/MassProductUpdate). It adds custom mass action along with the input field

Answer (score -1):

Massaction is already implemented in Product grid if you want to add one more action in the list you can create `app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml` in your module with code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <massaction name="listing_massaction" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions">
            <action name="status">
                <settings>
                    <type>status</type>
                    <label translate="true">Change status</label>
                    <actions>
                        <action name="0">
                            <type>enable</type>
                            <label translate="true">Enable in All Store Views</label>
                            <url path="catalog/product/massStatus">
                                <param name="status">1</param>
                            </url>
                        </action>
                        <action name="1">
                            <type>disable</type>
                            <label translate="true">Disable in All Store Views</label>
                            <url path="catalog/product/massStatus">
                                <param name="status">2</param>
                            </url>
                        </action>
                    </actions>
                </settings>
            </action>
        </massaction>
        <paging name="listing_paging"/>
    </listingToolbar>
</listing>
```

Hope it work!